# How to Return Github Issues from Private Repository (Node.js)

Tags: json, node.js, github, octokit

I am trying to return a list of Github issues from a private repo using Node.js.  I am able to return a list of the repos, but am struggling to return the issues.

It appears that you can list the issues with the `list_issues` function based on the documentation here `https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Issues.html`.  However, I get an error when trying to access the function.

```
const octokit = require('@octokit/rest')()

octokit.authenticate({
  type: 'basic',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password'
})

octokit.repos.getForOrg({
  org: 'name_of_organization',
  type: 'private'
}).then(({data, headers, status}) => {
  console.log(data) // returns list of repos as JSON
})

octokit.list_issues("name_of_org/name_of_repo")
  .then(({data, headers, status}) => {
  console.log(data) // error: octokit.list_issues in not a function
})
```

How can I return a list of private issues as JSON from Github?

Comment: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pagination helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation at: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Search-issues

While using the same authentication code block an example request might look like:

```
octokit.issues.getAll({
  filter: 'all',
  state: 'open',
  labels: '',
  sort: 'updated',
  direction: 'desc',
  since: '2018-07-01T00:00:00Z',
  per_page: '100',
  page: '1'})
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```